# Outputting recurring events within a loop VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently analyzing a schedule with color coded events that occur in a row and the time expands over the columns (there is only color in the cells no text, yes it's dumb but it's out of my control).  I am currently able to print the result for one occurrence of an event into another worksheet, but I cannot determine how to make it print the dates for recurring events in different cells (it currently only prints the last time an event occurs). My current code is:

```
For i = 2 To 93
    If Cells(7, i).Interior.Color = "8421631" And Cells(7, i - 1).Interior.Color = "16777215" Then
        startDay = Cells(3, i).Value
        startMonth = Cells(1, i).Value
        name = Cells(7, i).Value
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1) = startDay + startMonth

    End If
    If Cells(7, i).Interior.Color = "8421631" And Cells(7, i + 1).Interior.Color = "16777215" Then
        endDay = Cells(3, i).Value
        endMonth = Cells(1, i).Value
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2) = endDay + endMonth
    End If
Next i
```

All of my variables are entered as strings. I attempted a few different methods with no success. I feel that I need to add another loop in my IF statement, but I am unsure as to how to best do it.  **Overall the code achieves its purpose (previously used message boxes for output to confirm it was operating as it should).**  This is just a small part of the overall code, but with this answer I would be able to apply it elsewhere.

Comment: See how you did `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(..)`?  Do that with all the other references too. It may not be grabbing the data you expect, as without using the sheet, `Range()`, `Cells()`, `Row()`, etc. works on the `ActiveSheet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for what I could grasp out of your description you may try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To 93
        If Cells(7, i).Interior.Color = "8421631" Then
            If Cells(7, i - 1).Interior.Color = "16777215" Or Cells(7, i + 1).Interior.Color = "16777215" Then
                WriteDate Cells(3, i).Value, Cells(1, i).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Sub WriteDate(day As String, month As String)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1) = day & "/" & month
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a quick question since I am still learning the ins and outs of VBA.  What does adding the (.) before the Cells and Columns do to them?  I attempted to run the sub without those and it does not print any results.

Comment: You are welcome. The (.) is there to qualify what follows as a member of the object referenced in the preceeding "With" statement. In this case we have "With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")" so that both ".Cells" and ".Columns" are referenced as ranges of "Sheet1" worksheet of the currently active workbook, while without the (.) they would reference ranges in the currently active worksheet. Hope this helped clarifying. Finally you may want to mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.
        .